# Opening related links

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am working with the colorbox plugin to create modal windows for my web app.  I am having a little trouble opening a `<div>` that is related to `<a>`.

**Ideal behavior** 
Clicking on: 
`<a rel="id_123"></a>` 
should open up a **form** with the contents in: 
`div rel="id_123"></div>`

Check out my code here for clarification: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4GGS/6/

Thanks!

**EDIT:** This is what I have tried so far.  When a link is clicked, the click event will create a modal with ALL of the listings instead of the related ones. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Q4GGS/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DIV's don't have rel attributes.  You need to replace those with something else (such as a class or an ID).  Example JS:

```
$('.dialog_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.colorbox ({
        href: "#" + this.rel,
        width: '50%',
        inline: true
    });
});
```

Example HTML:

```
    <div class="ticket_details" id="id_123">
        text
    </div>
    <div class="ticket_details" id="id_124">
        text
    </div>
```

Comment: It is recommended that readers view the js fiddle example cited in the question to get the full context of Jack's answer.